# Given a list of strings, search a specific column for matching strings and return index value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The goal: I have a excel sheet with three columns. "BigList" containing about ~1000 genes. "Expression" with numeric gene expression values. "SmallList" containing small list of ~10 genes I am interested in.

For each gene in "SmallList", I want to search for its index in BigList and use that index to retrieve the expression value.

Here is what I tried so far. I used Pandas to read my excel file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Me\Box\Excel.xlsx', 
                    sheet_name='Genes')
```

Then I save my small list of genes "SmallList" into new a variable without NA values.

```
SmallList = df["SmallList"].dropna().tolist()
```

When I try to use this chunk of code, I get the following error message

```
df.loc[df['BigList'] == SmallList[1].index[0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The code return an index if I use SmallList[0]. But going higher than 0 gives me the error above. I'm going insane trying to figure this out.

I tried to manually type my "SmallList"

```
SmallList = ["GeneA", "GeneB", "GeneC"]
```

and I was able to avoid the error. I got indices for SmallList[1] and SmallList[2]. I don't understand why this is happening? I hope someone can explain this to me.

Using my manually created SmallList, I was able to get a list of indices the way I wanted.

```
indices = []
for i in range(0, len(SmallList)):
    indices += df.index[df['BigList'] == SmallList[i].tolist()

indices
[315, 148, 165]
```

Comment: in ```df.loc[df['BigList'] == SmallList[1].index[0]``` what is the value of ```SmallList[1]```?

Comment: @ewong the value should be a string. For instance, SmallList[1] = "GeneB". SmallList[2] = "GeneC" .. etc. If I try to manually type "GeneB" in the df.loc code line instead of SmallList[1], the code works perfectly. It will find the index of GeneB in BigList column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (if I understand the goal correctly).  First, create test data:

```
import pandas as pd

big = pd.DataFrame({
    'gene': ['GeneA', 'GeneB', 'GeneC', 'GeneD', 'GeneE', ],
    'expression': ['exp-A', 'exp-B', 'exp-C', 'exp-D', 'exp-E', ]})

small = pd.DataFrame({
    'gene': ['GeneA', 'GeneC', 'GeneE'],})
```

Second, do a left-join (keeping all items in the small list, and pulling in items from the big list with matching genes.  Note that big.reset_index() will put the `big` index values into the result set.

```
result = (pd.merge(left=small, 
                   right=big.reset_index(), 
                   on='gene', 
                   how='left')
            .rename(columns={'index': 'big_list_index'})
)
print(result)

    gene  big_list_index expression
0  GeneA               0      exp-A
1  GeneC               2      exp-C
2  GeneE               4      exp-E
```